# jQuery image sliders and their images

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and image sliders. Is it best practice to make the images that I want to slide the same size as the slider container that holds them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about best practice, it depends on your needs,
but creating a slider (novice) in javascript/jQuery it's most easier to have it **same width**,

- you can much easily control the sliding parent position...
- you don't need to do CSS trickery to maintain your images centered...
- you don't need to do javascript calculations about the *sliding space left*...
- one day you can replace your images with DIV elements that will hold more data...

### *[example gallery](http://jsbin.com/ifilel/edit#javascript,html,live)*

Answer (score 1):

@Roko already explained everything you need to know. On my behalf, I just want to share with you this link: [Learn jQuery in 30 days](http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/). This course helped me a lot with mastering jQuery and it contains an example of slider with guide by great jQuery ninja - Jeffrey Way. I strongly recommend you to look at it and surely this time will not be wasted. Have fun!

Comment: The ninja has more that 30 lines of code for what??? I would not do all that mess he is doing. Take a look at my code. Created in 10 min. and , yes, after you learn the basics, it's terribly simple.

Comment: Yes it is simpler, can't argue. However the guy bundled everything as self contained, easily customizable jQuery plugin.